# SlidingPaneLayout rendering problems on older APIs

Tags: android, android-listview, android-fragments, slidingpanelayout

I'm writing an app that uses the compatibility library and a SlidingPaneLayout. One of the panes contains a ListView. (The main pane is a SupportMapFragment object and it is working like a charm).

The problem is that, when I update the listview data, via `getLoaderManager().restartLoader(0, null, listFragment);`, and then I open the pane, it is not rendered correctly. And that only happens on older devices.

Follows an screen-shot of the problem:

[image]

In this screen-shot, the ListView pane is opened, but is not being shown correctly. It seems that it is being rendered underneath the SupportMapFragment...

Any ideas on what can be causing this weird behaviour or on what can I do to fix/bypass it?